# How to display right path with json

Tags: android, json, path

I am creating news reader app. I stuck on one part of code, everything else works. Problem is defining path to "title" and "url" in QueryUtils.

Here is what I need to read, from jsonpreetyprint

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "source": "bbc-news",
  "sortBy": "top",
  "articles": [
    {
      "author": "BBC News",
      "title": "China: Huawei arrest is rights abuse",
      "description": "The US seeks to extradite chief financial officer Meng Wanzhou, daughter of the telecom giant's founder.",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.bbc.co.uk\/news\/business-46465768",
      "urlToImage": "https:\/\/ichef.bbci.co.uk\/news\/1024\/branded_news\/CB73\/production\/_104638025_051019893.jpg",
      "publishedAt": "2018-12-06T09:49:44Z"
    }
```

I need to display title and url.

Here is code from QueryUtils

```
private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty( newsJSON )) {
            return null;
        }

        List<News> newsall = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
            JSONObject response = data.getJSONObject(RESPONSE);
            JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray(ARTICLES);
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(i);
                String webTitle = obj.getJSONArray( ARTICLES ).getJSONObject( 0 ).getString( WEB_TITLE );
                String webUrl = obj.getJSONArray( ARTICLES ).getJSONObject( 0 ).getString( WEB_URL );

                News news = new News(webTitle, webUrl);
                newsall.add(news);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
        }

        return newsall;
    }
```

I don't know how to get path to title and url. Strings webTitle and webUrl are wrong defined.

TY for help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, just empty view with my message "There are no new stories".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to the following:

```
try {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        JSONArray results = data.getJSONArray("articles");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = results.getJSONObject(i);
            String webTitle = obj.getString("title");
            String webUrl = obj.getString("url");

            News news = new News(webTitle, webUrl);
            newsall.add(news);
        }

    }
```

Firstly, you don't need to create a response JSONObject as you already have the data object. You should be able to access your arraylist of Articles directly from the data object. Secondly, within your for each loop, you can get the string easily by using the .getString methods and stating the string title of which value you want to extract.

Give it a try.